# Yesterday was the best day of my life

Tags: past-tense

Is it grammatically correct to say that Yesterday **is** the best day of my life instead of was?? My reasoning is that the best day of my life is yesterday. It has not changed.

If someone says yesterday was the best day of my life, does that mean yesterday is no longer the best of his/her life? Maybe he/she won the lottery today so he/she thinks that today is his best day instead of yesterday?

Comment: Without any context, "yestersday was" means that it was and it is still the "best ...". If you say, "Since I got the result of the lottery, yesterday was", then you can infer that it is no more true.

Comment: If you asked this question yesterday, or the day before, is yesterday still your best day? If so, then 'is' is correct, although the use is (slightly) humorous. Tomorrow, I'm sure, is the best day of most people's lives.

Comment: @JEL Why do i have to ask the question yesterday and the day before yesterday? Sorry, English is not my first language. Is that a test i should always use if something is true all the time before using simple present?

Comment: @Graffito If I were to say John was smart, does that mean John is no longer smart? I thought that the verb "was" indicates something in the past and it is no longer true anymore. So what makes it true in the past and in the present in the sentence Yesterday was the best day of my life? Thanks.

Comment: No, it is not a test you should always use. The simple present is used "To state facts or general truths". That yesterday was your best day is a specific truth; further, it (along with which day is yesterday) changes from day to day. So by now it may be the day before yesterday that was your best day. Would you say "tomorrow is my best day"? Not unless it is a *general* truth that you always consider 'tomorrow' your best day--otherwise, you would say "tomorrow will be my best day".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proper is: *Yesterday was the best day of my life.* When you experience a better day than yesterday, you will say *Yesterday had been the best day of my life*. The fact that something about the past remains true today is not germane: *George Washington was the first president of the United States.* That he was the first is still true, and it will always be true. But he achieved this distinction in the past and the simple past tense is meant exactly for that--to describe an action or situation that occurred in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks JEL. It seems like 'is/are' is used for general truths, not specific.

E.g.
Correct: "Those shoes from yesterday were mine."
Wrong: "Those shoes from yesterday are mine."

E.g.
Correct: "That woman yesterday is my mother."
Wrong: "That woman yesterday was my mother."

Comment: I don't see how this adds anything relevant. As pointed out in the accepted answer, the tense has nothing to do with the quality of the truthfulness of the statement, but at what moment the statement became/becomes true.